# Set variable equal to index count number

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

$ID = Array(0=>"12", 1=>"14, 2=>"27", 3=>"987", 4=>"23");

Then I have this function:

```
foreach ($doodads AS $doodad) {
    if ($page == 1) {
        $doodad['row'] = $X;
    } else {
        $doodad['row'] = count($all_ids) + $X;
    }

    $return[] = Doodads_Model_Ajax::formatCallbackDoodad($doodad);
}
```

How do I set `$X` equal to the number of the current index in array $ID (0, 1, 2, 3, or 4)?

Comment: We din't get your question. Can you please elaborate with some more details like what expected outcome you need etc

Comment: Tx Anant. I have the array and I need $X to equal to the current number (i.e. count) of the index. So, in the first loop, $X=0, in the second loop, $X=1, in the third loop, $X=2, etc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach to get the key and value instead of just the value.

```
foreach($doodads as $key => $doodad) {
    echo 'Key: ', $key, "\n";
    print_r($doodad);
}
```

In your case, $key would be $X;

```
foreach($doodads as $X => $doodad)
```

---

To count up in your for loop, try this.

```
$x = 0;
foreach($doodads as $key => $doodad) {
    echo 'Key: ', $key, "\n";
    echo 'X: ', $x, "\n\n";
    ++$x; // Add one to x.
}
```

Comment: Tx @Brogan.  Your solution sets $X equal to the current value of the index. I need to set it equal to the current number (i.e. count) of the index.  So, in the first loop, $X=0, in the second loop, $X=1, in the third loop, $X=2, etc. .  Any ideas?

Comment: Perfect, @Brogan. Thanks very much!